Can I use Visual Studio 2022 Community to build applications that are using old vc100 libs and dll?
I am currently working on a migration project and I am currently using visual studio 2010 and the boost library and build (bjam) to build my applications. I want to migrate to visual studio 2022, but am wondering if there are any dependencies I need to look out for. For example, I want to build my applications using vc100 libs and dlls with bjam but on visual studio 2022. Will there be a linkage problem where I will have to upgrade to the current boost library/build system because of compatibility requirements?
Currently, I have compiled my boost library (version 1.67) on the old boost build system (bjam) that compiles through the vc100 toolset. I want to build an application on Visual Studio 2022 linking to these libraries, but am getting errors like this:
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000AA2) "public: static class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const & __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::codecvt(void)" (?codecvt@path@filesystem@boost@@$$FSAABV?
I am unsure if this is because of the version dependency because I was able to build a separate application using this method.  However, based on the error, it might be because I am using a linker dependency on the boost filesystem library on this application and this may be the source of the errors.
